# How to Prevent 'Secret Key' appearing in Logon Screen

Tags: joomla-3.x, joomla-3.4

Can someone please let me know how I prevent the 'Secret Key' from appearing in the Log On screen?

At the moment, the Username, Password and 'Secret Key' appear in the Log On screen when users attempt to login to my site. I  would just like the username  and password to appear.

Thank you.

Carlton.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Go to Extensions | Plugins
Select Type `twofactorauth`
Unpublish `Two Factor Authentication - Google Authenticator` plugin.